# Bug in .Net's `Random` class?

Tags: c#, .net, random, fisher-yates-shuffle

I was looking at a question that was talking about a bad implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm and I was perplexed that there was a bias when implemented incorrectly.

The two algorithms are these:

```
private Random _random = new Random();

public int[] FisherYates(int[] source)
{
    int[] output = source.ToArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        var j = _random.Next(i, output.Length);
        (output[i], output[j]) = (output[j], output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

public int[] FisherYatesBad(int[] source)
{
    int[] output = source.ToArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        var j = _random.Next(0, output.Length);
        (output[i], output[j]) = (output[j], output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

A really subtle different, but enough to cause a massive bias.

Good implementation:

[image: Good Fisher-Yates]

Bad implementation:

[image: Bad Fisher-Yates]

To be clear about these plots, I start with the numbers 0 to 99, create 10_000_000 shuffles using whichever algorithm and then I average the values in each of the shuffles to get a single set of figures. If the shuffle is trying random then all 100 figures would belong to the same normal distribution.

Now, that's all fine, but I thought I'd check to see if these methods produce valid results:

```
public int[] OrderByRandomNext(int[] source) => source.OrderBy(x => _random.Next()).ToArray();

public int[] OrderByRandomNextDouble(int[] source) => source.OrderBy(x => _random.NextDouble()).ToArray();
```

Both nice a neat, but are they a fair shuffle?

`OrderByRandomNext`:

[image: OrderByRandomNext]

`OrderByRandomNextDouble`:

[image: OrderByRandomNextDouble]

Notice that the `1` and the `100` figures are significantly lower in each?

Well, I thought it might be an artefact of how `OrderBy` works. So I tested it with another random number generator - one brought to use from Eric Lippert in his improving Random series.

```
public int[] OrderByBetterRandomNextDouble(int[] source) => source.OrderBy(x => BetterRandom.NextDouble()).ToArray();

public static class BetterRandom
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<RandomNumberGenerator> crng =
        new ThreadLocal<RandomNumberGenerator>(RandomNumberGenerator.Create);

    private static readonly ThreadLocal<byte[]> bytes =
        new ThreadLocal<byte[]>(() => new byte[sizeof(int)]);

    public static int NextInt()
    {
        crng.Value.GetBytes(bytes.Value);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Value, 0) & int.MaxValue;
    }

    public static double NextDouble()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            long x = NextInt() & 0x001FFFFF;
            x <<= 31;
            x |= (long)NextInt();
            double n = x;
            const double d = 1L << 52;
            double q = n / d;
            if (q != 1.0)
                return q;
        }
    }
}
```

Well, here's the chart:

[image: BetterRandom]

There's no bias!

Here's my code to generate the data (run in LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    var n = 100;
    var s = 1000000;

    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();

    var algorithms = new Func<int[], int[]>[]
    {
        FisherYates,
        OrderByRandomNext,
        OrderByRandomNextDouble,
        OrderByBetterRandomNextDouble,
    };

    var averages =
        algorithms
            .Select(algorithm =>
                Enumerable
                    .Range(0, numbers.Length)
                    .Select(x =>
                        Enumerable
                            .Range(0, s)
                            .Select(y => algorithm(numbers))
                            .Aggregate(0.0, (a, v) => a + (double)v[x] / s))
                    .ToArray())
            .Select(x => new
            {
                averages = x,
                distribution = Accord.Statistics.Distributions.Univariate.NormalDistribution.Estimate(x.Skip(1).SkipLast(1).ToArray()),
                first = x.First(),
                last = x.Last(),
            })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.averages,
                x.distribution,
                x.first,
                x.last,
                first_prob =x.distribution.DistributionFunction(x.first),
                last_prob = x.distribution.DistributionFunction(x.last),
            })
            .ToArray();

    var d = 

    averages.Dump();
}

private Random _random = new Random();

    public int[] FisherYates(int[] source)
    {
        int[] output = source.ToArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
        {
            var j = _random.Next(i, output.Length);
            (output[i], output[j]) = (output[j], output[i]);
        }
        return output;
    }

public int[] OrderByRandomNext(int[] source) => source.OrderBy(x => _random.Next()).ToArray();

public int[] OrderByRandomNextDouble(int[] source) => source.OrderBy(x => _random.NextDouble()).ToArray();

    public int[] OrderByBetterRandomNextDouble(int[] source) => source.OrderBy(x => BetterRandom.NextDouble()).ToArray();

    public static class BetterRandom
    {
        private static readonly ThreadLocal<RandomNumberGenerator> crng =
            new ThreadLocal<RandomNumberGenerator>(RandomNumberGenerator.Create);

        private static readonly ThreadLocal<byte[]> bytes =
            new ThreadLocal<byte[]>(() => new byte[sizeof(int)]);

        public static int NextInt()
        {
            crng.Value.GetBytes(bytes.Value);
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Value, 0) & int.MaxValue;
        }

        public static double NextDouble()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                long x = NextInt() & 0x001FFFFF;
                x <<= 31;
                x |= (long)NextInt();
                double n = x;
                const double d = 1L << 52;
                double q = n / d;
                if (q != 1.0)
                    return q;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the data that I generated:

```
distribution                                             | first              | last               | first_prob             | last_prob            
-------------------------------------------------------- | ------------------ | ------------------ | ---------------------- | ---------------------
N(x; μ = 49.50267467345823, σ² = 0.0008896228453062147)  | 49.505465999987585 | 49.49833699998965  | 0.5372807100387846     | 0.44218570467529394  
N(x; μ = 49.50503062243786, σ² = 0.0009954477334487531)  | 49.36330799998817  | 49.37124399998651  | 3.529550818615057E-06  | 1.115772521409486E-05
N(x; μ = 49.505720877539765, σ² = 0.0008257970106087029) | 49.37231699998847  | 49.386660999990106 | 1.7228855271333998E-06 | 1.712972513601141E-05
N(x; μ = 49.49994663264188, σ² = 0.0007518765247716318)  | 49.50191999998847  | 49.474235999989205 | 0.5286859991636343     | 0.17421285127499514
```

Here's my question. What's up with `System.Random` and the bias it introduces?

Comment: I don't understand how `FisherYatesBad` could produce that nicely ordered parabolic result. I've used that algorithm and it shuffled stuff as expected.

Comment: I think it would be useful to describe what the plots are actually plotting, i.e. label axises etc.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?  The algorithm for `Random()` without a seed [was changed recently](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/47085) and might be applied to newer .NET versions.  See also: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23198 .

Comment: Is the problem that `first_prob` and `last_prob` are too small in the two middle rows? I've run this locally (with a smaller `s` as it takes a very long time) and I get values like 0.72&0.33 for `OrderByRandomNext` and .82&.68 for `OrderByBetterRandomNextDouble`, although they change across runs.

Comment: @Andrew - I've provided two implementations of Fisher-Yates - one correct and one bad. The bad one does indeed produce what looks like a parabolic result. You see the parabolic effect clearly after generating 10 million samples.

Comment: @JonasH - I took the numbers 0 to 99 and then shuffled them. That produces 100 numbers that, in theory, should have an equal chance of appearing in any position. The theoretical average is 49.5. I then compute the average value in each position and I've plotted those.

Comment: @PeterO. - I've used .Net Framework 4.7.2 and .Net 5.0.6. Both have the same bias.

Comment: @Andrew - You need to run 10 million or so as the bias doesn't show clearly before then. It's the averaging that removes the bias. The chances of the first and last values, when using `System.Random`, appearing in the normal distribution is represented by the `first_prob` and `last_prob` values. They are both exceedingly unlikely to belong to the standard distribution defined by the internal values of each array.

Comment: Do you think the problem is actually in `Random` or the fact that you're not matching the expectations of `OrderBy`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I initially thought that `OrderBy` might have been the culprit, but that's why I also tried with `BetterRandom`. Since that removed the bias I figured that `OrderBy` behaves properly.

Comment: Good question! As noted in the given answer, there are a lot of sources of bias in the default implementation of `Random`. A particularly vexing source of bias is that there are 2^226 possible shuffles but only 2^32 possible seeds, so the vast, vast majority of possible shuffles are never generated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default RNG in .NET up to (and including) .NET 5 has known bias and performance issues, most documented here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23198:

- A typo in the implementation of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator with unknown practical effects.
- A different modulo (2^32-1 instead of a power of two) with unknown practical effects.
- `Next(0, int.MaxValue)` has heavy bias.
- `NextDouble()` only produces 2^31 possible values, where it could pick from approx. 2^62 distinct values.

This is why .NET 6 implemented a better algorithm ([xoshiro256**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xoshiro256**)). You will get this better RNG when you instantiate a `new Random()` instance without a seed. This is described in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/47085. Unfortunately, it's not easy to replace the old RNG when a seed is provided since people might rely on the behavior of the current, biased RNG.

Even though xoshiro256** has some [documented flaws](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/a-quick-look-at-xoshiro256.html) (and a [rebuttal](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8gx2d3/new_line_of_fast_prngs_released_by_the_author_of/dyqe1u4/)) as well, I found it to work pretty well for my purposes. I [have copied](https://github.com/deiruch/Extensions/blob/master/Extensions/Random.cs) the [improved implementation from .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.Xoshiro256StarStarImpl.cs) and use that.

Side-note: LINQ queries are lazily evaluated (a.k.a. "deferred execution"). If you use a RNG in the `.OrderBy` lambda, you might get confusing results if you iterate multiple times, because the order might change every time. Some sorting algorithms rely on the fact that elements won't suddenly change their relative order to work correctly. Returning inconsistent ordering values will break such sorting algorithms. Sure, todays `OrderBy` implementation in LINQ-to-Objects works fine, but there's no documented guarantee that it has to work with "randomly"-changing values. A reasonable alternative is `.OrderBy(e => HashCode.Combine(0x1337, e))`.

Comment: A good answer, but I disagree that the `HashCode.Combine` alternative is reasonable. Why do you think so?

Comment: I would still like to know why the first and last numbers are affected like they are. I agree this is a smoking gun, but it's still not proof of the error.

Comment: `HashCode.Combine` tries to distribute bits slightly, and will produce new values every program invocation. In my tests I didn't see biased averages. If you want higher certainty, you should of course use a cryptographic hash and a better seed.

Comment: If you want proof, you'd have to analyze the behavior of Knuth's RNG with different modulus and configuration. That's out of my league, sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a bit too mad professor level for me too.

Comment: For those still not using .Net 6 (because it's not yet released :P), one can use the [XoshiroPRNG.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XoshiroPRNG.Net/) package. It provides a performant implementation of several PRNGs in the "Xoshiro family". I am the maintainer of that package, and if you need an algo I haven't coded, feel free to ask.

Comment: I think there might be some misunderstanding here about the practice of producing a shuffle by providing a random key.  Though as the question notes, certain choices of RNG can produce bias, the fundamental technique of "associate a random key with each item and sort by that key" is fine in LINQ.  The implementation generates each key exactly once and stores it; the key generating lambda is NOT called every time that the item is encountered during the sort.

Comment: What is NOT fine is the technique of "sort with a comparison where the comparison operation randomly says "bigger", "smaller" or "equal" for arbitrary pairs. A comparison operator is required to produce a total order: that is, A==B implies B==A, A<B implies B>A, and most commonly violated, transitivity works. If A<B and B<C then A<C.  A random comparison does not meet these requirements and therefore the sort algorithm can behave strangely.

Comment: All that said, the more general point made in this answer is worth keeping in mind. Executing a query twice can unexpectedly produce different results, either because the underlying collection changed or because the lambdas in the query are impure. If your program logic relies upon queries producing the same results twice, then you need to do work to ensure that you are not in one of those situations.